# Java bluetooth app in android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am starting to develop a bluetooth application for mobiles. My project guide reccomended that we use Java for developing. I was trying to find out whether Java apps can run on android. I read that only the UI is different. But in the case of bluetooth, would the APIs and connection be the same or different? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question does not fit to stackoverflow, overly broad , here in stackoverflow , we expect question to be a programming problem, more precise and reasonably scoped. For you, I'd suggest to get started with a good tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Java is the primary language of choice for Android apps. In your specific case of Bluetooth, the Android API provides its own classes for everything. You can find a full documentation on that [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html).

In terms of Java-specific Android development, check out [this link](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920001690.do), [this one](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/java-tutorial/), or the [many others](https://www.google.com/search?q=developing+java+android+apps).

Comment: If you can imagine an entire book or a Google search that answers OP's question, that question does not fit on Stackoverflow :-)

Comment: Better to answer and have the question removed than to ignore it and leave a question unanswered. :)

Comment: Better to comment on the question and close the question citing the reason, answering such questions will entertain newbies to ask more such questions .This will make the life of moderators harder. You should NEVER entertain such questions by answering them. :)